# How can I compare and match strings from separate elements?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML with two separate .`parentN` elements which contain `.item`. Each item from `parent1` contains a string and each item from `parent2` contains the same string but their order is mixed up.

```
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="item">Some Text 1</div>
   <div class="item">Some Other Text 123</div>
   <div class="item">Yet another Text 6</div>
   <div class="item">Something else</div>
   <div class="item">Blabla</div>
   ....
</div>

<div class="parent2">      
   <div class="item">
     <span class="title">Blabla</span>
     <span class="ctgr">category 1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <span class="title">Yet another Text 6</span>
      <span class="ctgr">category 33</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Text 1</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Cat 12</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Other Text 123</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Lala 12</span>
   </div>   
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Something else</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Zaza</span>
   </div>
   ... 
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. Compare every item's string from first list with every string in `<span class="title">` from the other,
2. match them,
3. if there is a matching couple, then add a `data` attribute in every item of first list containing the ctgr string of the corresponding item in list 2.

So the result would be something like this:

```
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="item" data-ctgr="Cat 12">Some Text 1</div>
   <div class="item" data-ctgr="Lala">Some Other Text 123</div>
   <div class="item" data-ctgr="category 33">Yet another Text 6</div>
   <div class="item" data-ctgr="Zaza">Something else</div>
   <div class="item" data-ctgr="category 1">Blabla</div>
   ....
</div>

<div class="parent2">      
   <div class="item">
     <span class="title">Blabla</span>
     <span class="ctgr">category 1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <span class="title">Yet another Text 6</span>
      <span class="ctgr">category 33</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Text 1</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Cat 12</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Other Text 123</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Lala 12</span>
   </div>   
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Something else</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Zaza</span>
   </div>
   ... 
</div>
```

I know that I need to start with two `.each()` iterations, one for every parent, but I don't know how to continue after that and I need some ideas to continue.

```
$('.parent1 .item').each(function() {
   var p1Text = $(this).text();
});

$('.parent2 .item').each(function() {
   var p2Text = $(this).text();
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: First, your second loop selector should be `.parent2 .item .title` (look carefully the HTML you provide us). Then, I propose you to initialize two arrays, one for `parent1` and an another for `parent2`, and to fill them respectively thanks to your two `each()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops for this. You can do it in one by looping through the `.parent2 .item` elements and then using `filter()` to find `.parent1 .item` elements where the text matches, like this:

```js
$('.parent2 .item').each(function() {
  var $item = $(this);
  var title = $item.find('.title').text().trim();
  var ctgr = $item.find('.ctgr').text().trim();
  
  $('.parent1 .item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == title;
  }).data('ctgr', ctgr);
}); 

// for testing only:
$('.parent1 .item').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('ctgr'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="item">Some Text 1</div>
   <div class="item">Some Other Text 123</div>
   <div class="item">Yet another Text 6</div>
   <div class="item">Something else</div>
   <div class="item">Blabla</div>
</div><br /><br />

<div class="parent2">      
   <div class="item">
     <span class="title">Blabla</span>
     <span class="ctgr">category 1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <span class="title">Yet another Text 6</span>
      <span class="ctgr">category 33</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Text 1</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Cat 12</span>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Some Other Text 123</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Lala 12</span>
   </div>   
   <div class="item">
       <span class="title">Something else</span>
       <span class="ctgr">Zaza</span>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is very correct, the only thing that needs to change is the .data and be substituted with .attr('data-ctgr', xxxx)

Thank you very much Rory, i accept your answer